# Get this javascript function to scroll to an area

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the JS function that when clicking a link will put a quote into a textarea, is there a way I can get it to then scroll to an a tag with an id of "commentbox"?

```
function insert_quote(quote_id, username)
{
    var text = document.getElementById(quote_id).innerHTML;

    var bbcode = $("textarea").sceditor('instance').toBBCode(text);

    $('textarea').sceditor('instance').insert('[quote=' + username + ']' + bbcode + "[/quote]\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code should scroll your page to tag "#commentbox".

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#commentbox").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

You can set duration of this animation by changing 2000 to another value (in miliseconds).